# Como transformar um "Projeto Unity" em um .EXE?

Tags: unity3d

Estou acompanhando os vídeos do Nils no YouTube.  Após a criação de um projeto no Unity, como faço um instalador/.EXE para ele? Para rodar em Android, Windows, e outros.

Comment: Oi Pablo, editei sua pergunta pra ficar mais no formato do site ok? Aqui a gente não pergunta direto pra outro usuário, qualquer um pode responder. E, com a tag certa ([tag:unity-3d]), é bem provável que o Nils veja e responda. Agora é só esperar uma resposta, boa sorte!

Comment: No caso `.exe` (ou `.msi`) seria no Windows para Desktop, Android seria o `.apk`. Eu nunca trabalhei com unity-3d, mas acredito que precise do `Android Studio`, iOS vai necessitar do `XCode` (somente Macs) e Windows do `Visual Studio`.

Comment: Eu consigo complementar a resposta de alguém?
O Guilherme Nascimento e o DolbyCpp já responderam uma parte. Mas seria bom mostrar como faz.
Primeiro tem que ir em File>>>BuildSettings (ctrl+shift+b - trocar o ctrl pelo command no mac).
Vai aparecer isso aqui http://i.imgur.com/JFrTKTD.png
Escolher a plataforma que deseja construir o jogo, no caso do android e ios é conforme Guilherme falou, no caso de exe não tem problema se estiver desenvolvendo direto em windows. Para mais detalhes consultar a informação no link que o DolbyCpp postou. (e mandar traduzir a página se o idioma for um problema).

Comment: Oi @Nils. Você poderia editar a resposta de alguém, mas eu acho que faz mais sentido você dar uma resposta adicional própria. :)

Comment: Quanto mais respostas, melhor. Desde que uma não seja cópia da outra em todos seus detalhes, como às vezes acontece :) Mas se tem algo a mais para dizer, merece um resposta nem que seja só para complementar. Quem sabe ela fica tão boa que ela é que acabe sendo aceita como a melhor.

Comment: Agora entendi bem. Obrigado pelo ***LINK*** @DolbyCpp ira ajudar bastante, Obrigado a todos por terem ajudado a tirar minha duvida! :)

Comment: Minha pergunta ja foi respondida mas eu estava dando uma estudada, e me veio uma duvida, não vi a opção de "Exportar" para (Java).jar, provavelmente porque o programa não tem essa função, mas caso eu queira "exportar" para .jar oque eu devo fazer ?!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Exportar teu projeto do Unity para as plataformas disponíveis

### Conteúdo

1. Premissas
2. Configurar o Player
3. Para Exportar
4. Standalone - Windows, Mac & Linux
5. Android.
6. iOS.

> Atualizado para Unity 5.0.0.

#### Premissas

Para exportar o teu programa/jogo feito em Unity você precisa primeiro definir a plataforma alvo, pois dependendo da plataforma vai precisar de uns arquivos adicionas, ou contas de desenvolvedor para poder rodar ele.

Além disso você precisará configurar o "Player" - que na verdade é um menu com as configurações do teu jogo.

TL;DR(vídeo no youtube) - http://youtu.be/gK93-LGPp-c

---

#### Configurar o Player

Vá em `Edit > Project Sttings > Player` , conforme a seguinte figura.

[image: Editar o Player]

No Inspector aparecerá alguns detalhes para você configurar, o importante é definir o que é padrão para todos.

[image: Player no Inspector]

Configurações padrões:

- **Default Company** - Nome da tua empresa [importante]
- **Product Name**    - Nome do teu jogo    [importante]
- **Default Icon**    - Ícone do jogo       [importante]
- **Default Cursor**  - Como vai ficar o mouse no jogo
- **Cursor Hotspot**  - Parte do cursor que "funciona" - ex: você pode fazer uma mão e escolher que só o dedinho funcione.

As outras vão depender para onde você quer exportar.

---

#### Para exportar

Vá em `File > Buid Settings` ou `Ctrl+Shift+B` (cmd+shif+b no mac)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Certifique-se que todas as cenas do teu jogo estão em Scenes in Build

#### Windows, Mac & Linux - StandAlone

O Unity exporta por padrão para estes formatos, sem precisar de nada adicional.

Você só precisa escolher:

- **Target Plataform **  - Qual o sistema operacional alvo, Windows, Linux ou Mac
- **Architecture**       - Arquitetura do processador
  O resto é opcional e depende do que você quer fazer.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Mais detalhes http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PlayerSettingsStandalone.html

#### Android

Primeiro você precisa ter o Android SDK instalado no teu computador. Se você não sabe o que é isso, está no lugar errado e não deveria estar fazendo jogos para ele(ha-ha). Brincadeiras a parte, acesse o site oficial de desenvolvedor do android: http://developer.android.com/sdk/

Procure pela opção outros downloads ("**Other Download Options**" da ultima vez que acessei).

E baixe a versão para teu sistema operacional que corresponde a SDK Tools Only

Após instalado, abra o Unity. Clique em `Edit > Preferences...`. Escolha `External Tools`, e em `Android SDK Location` escolha onde você instalou ele.

[image: Android SDK Location]

Agora vá no Build Settings e escolha o Android como opção de plataforma.

[image: Android Build Settings]

Obs: Quando você mandar compilar e não aparecer a barra de progresso é sinal que alguma coisa aconteceu de forma errada.

> Mais detalhes http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-GettingStarted.html

#### iOS

Um do mais chatos de exportar.

Você precisará ter uma conta de [desenvolvedor Apple](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/), cumprir os requerimentos para instalar o [iOS SDK](https://developer.apple.com/ios/download/) (geralmente instalar o iTunes e atualizar o sistema). Não use versão beta, sempre vá na recente mais estável.

Siga o passo a passo do portal de desenvolvimento da apple para configurar tudo que ele te pedir - adicionar pessoas, dispositivos, certificados, instalar outras coisas... até a resposta para esse modo é tão chata de escrever.

Dependendo do que for fazer vai dar muito mais ou só muito trabalho, como adicionar compras no aplicativo, chamadas de bibliotecas, e por ai vai.

Lembrando que os projetos são gerados em xcode, e depois você precisa tunar algumas configurações como as travas de fps dos dispositivos com iOS.

> Mais informações http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/iphone-GettingStarted.html
>
> Video para testar o teu jogo (funciona para android também) https://youtu.be/BXHd-67Q98w

#### BlackBerry

#### Windows Phone 8.1

#### Web Player

#### WebGL (Preview)

#### Consoles

**TODO** : Preciso juntar os links e materiais para cada caso pois vai levar um tempinho, mas o que tem até agora já responde a dúvida inicial.

Comment: Uoo! Mas que ótima a explicação, a principio só vai ira "servir" quando eu conseguir finalizar minha ideia/projeto. mas de qualquer forma já irei finalizar entendendo esta parte ... 
Estudar muito (...) :]. Gracias! @Nils

Answer (score 5):

A extensão **.exe** é reconhecida apenas pelas versões do Windows. Outros sistemas operacionais trabalham com outras extensões(Android com **.apk**, e assim por diante).

Você precisa compilar seu projeto para cada plataforma onde deseja roda-lo.

A própria documentação da Unity fala a respeito disto: [Platform Specific](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformSpecific.html)(Vá expandindo os menus).

Boa sorte.

Comment: Grato irmão, valeu pela Força!

Comment: @Nils - Minha pergunta ja foi respondida mas eu estava dando uma estudada, e me veio uma duvida, não vi a opção de "Exportar" para (Java).jar, provavelmente porque o programa não tem essa função, mas caso eu queira "exportar" para .jar oque eu devo fazer ?!